# Send ping message from autobahn android websocket client

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

I'm using autobahn android web socket library to build my web socket client application.
In order to keep the web socket connection alive for a long time, I need to periodically send ping messages from the client.

How can I do that with auotbahn android web socket library?

Answer (score 0):

AutobahnAndroid's WebSocketWriter [supports](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/dc1ea70e21ccbe966de8d5d565d7921362d28bfb/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketWriter.java#L247) client pong messages, and AutobahnPython [claims](http://autobahn.ws/python/websocketintro.html#ping-pong-processing) the following:

> explicit processing of Pings/Pongs is unnecessary normally - AutobahnPython will do the right thing under the hood.

However, during execution of a simple chat client-server setup, I observe no such ping/pong heartbeat messages.

From what I have read, it is unclear from both the documentation and the source, what the full requirements are for enabling implicit Autobahn* heartbeats.

My personal solution involves issuing a ping from the server during *onConnection* and the appropriate *onMesssage*, and something similar to the following client code *onMessage*:

```
if (payload.equals("ping from the server"))) {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
                myWebSocket.sendTextMessage("pong from the client");
            }
    }, 1000L);
}
```

... which schedules a pong response to be sent by the client, 1 second after receiving a ping from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pull request that I just submitted

https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/pull/67

which adds sendPingMessage(byte[] payload) and onPongMessage(byte[] payl).